# I want the screen to be cleared/completely black when the enter key is pressed. How would I do that?

Tags: python, pygame

I want the screen to change to all black after the enter button is pressed.

I was trying to have the screen clear here, when the enter key gets pressed:

```
def newScreen(self):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                pygame.win.fill(self,(0,0,0))
```

Comment: `win.fill((0,0,0))` instead of `pygame.win.fill(self,(0,0,0))`

Comment: We need to see your whole code or atleast a minimal reproducible example. If you have a display surface called `win` then do what @Rabbid76 said. That'll fill the whole screen black.

Answer (score 2):

```
for event in pygame.event.get(): 
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: 
        if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN: 
            win.fill((0,0,0))
```

Even this will not work if you have a bigger code that is blitting something else on the screen like a background in the while loop as it will again blit the background and black screen would be visible for a micro second thus you will need to define a variable(black_fill is my name) and set its value as False and if not black_fill: than only blit the other images and else: win.fill((0,0,0)).Also when enter is pressed( the way you tracked its clicking by events) just make black_fill as True.

```
win = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 500))
black_fill = False
bg = pygame.image.load('any_bg_file')
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: 
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN: 
                black_fill = True
    if not black_fill:
        win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    else:
        win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```